# The leading tone diminished chord of Bb major

Tags: chords, chord-theory

At 6:38-ish in

The guy says he replaced the Gm with the `leading tone diminished chord (of Bb major)`, but I don't get how he got that to be B-diminished?

Isn't the `leading tone diminished of Bb major` A-diminished? (Because A is the leading tone of Bb-major scale)

Who is wrong here? Him or me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're both correct, but the person in the video should have been more clear. He should have said that the B diminished seventh chord is the leading-tone chord *of the ensuing C-minor chord*.

Because it's viio7 of C minor, that Bo7 functions to briefly make C minor sound like tonic even though the piece as a whole is in B-flat.

Comment: Ah, I guess he is not using the natural minor then! I don't why, but I always neglect the harmonic and melodic minor.

Comment: I hear it more as replacing a diatonic vi with a secondary dominant to the ii as opposed to a new tonic.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I agree 100%, that's exactly what it's doing. But the logic of a tonicization is that it briefly points to a new tonic.

Comment: True, the leading tone resolving makes a non tonic chord sound more important...or more something!

Answer (score 3):

You are right that the leading tone diminished chord of Bb is A diminished but in this case he is talking about using the leading tone diminished chord of the Cm chord which is B diminished.